# Finding the max. zoom level containing imagery at a point in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google, maps

Is there a way to find the maximum zoom level containing imagery at a point in GMaps?

I'm wanting to automatically zoom my map in as much as possible when a user chooses a point, but sometimes there is no hi-res imagery (i.e. only level 18, not 21) at that point?

Is there a way to know beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems it's precisely the function of the MaxZoom service of the V3 JS api :

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MaxZoomService